# Multiple update statements in one StoredProcedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am wondering if it is possible to have multiple Update statements in a store procedure

Something like this:

```
Update Table1 set field1 = @new_value where id = @table1_id

Update Table2 set field2 = @new_value where id = @table2_id

Update Table3 set field3 = @new_value where id = @table3_id
```

Right now I am executing them seperately but as they are only used together I wonder if they could be located in just one SP.

Comment: this is one reason to use stored procedures, add a transaction and error handling and you have a good solution

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_update (@table1_id INT, @table2_id INT, @table3_id INT, @new_value INT)
AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE  Table1
        SET     field1 = @new_value
        WHERE   id = @table1_id

        UPDATE  Table2
        SET     field2 = @new_value
        WHERE   id = @table2_id

        UPDATE  Table3
        SET     field3 = @new_value
        WHERE   id = @table3_id
END
```

Comment: wow that is slightly embarrassing, I of course tried this and kept getting syntax errors and somehow draw the conclusion it wasn't possible this way, just tried it again and works perfect! Thanks :)

Comment: @The real napster: Would you mark Quassnoi's answer as answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that works fine.

Also put this in the stored procedure before the updates:

```
set nocount on
```

This keeps the stored procedures from creating result sets for queries without a result. Otherwise each update will produce an empty result set that is sent back to the client.

Answer (score 6):

You should wrap those statments in transactions as well so that if one fails all are rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the stored procedure with transaction , nocounton and multiple update queries.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE prc_update (@table1_id INT, @table2_id INT, @table3_id INT, 
 @new_value INT)
 AS
 BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY

 Set Nocount ON
 Begin Transaction
 Save Transaction BeforeTransactionSavePoint
    UPDATE  Table1
    SET     field1 = @new_value
    WHERE   id = @table1_id

    UPDATE  Table2
    SET     field2 = @new_value
    WHERE   id = @table2_id

    UPDATE  Table3
    SET     field3 = @new_value
    WHERE   id = @table3_id
   Commit Transaction
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH

If @@TRANCOUNT > 0
Rollback Tran BeforeTransactionSavePoint
DECLARE  
 @ErMessage NVARCHAR(2048),  
 @ErSeverity INT,  
 @ErState INT  

 SELECT  
 @ErMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
 @ErSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
 @ErState = ERROR_STATE()  

 RAISERROR (@ErMessage,@ErSeverity,@ErState )  
 END
```

Comment: Is there any way to write those error statements to a table, if I am executing this stored proc from an Access front end?