# Update 2 tables from Edit Action (ViewModel).

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I want first to say sorry, because I'm new to this programming language, so forgive me if I say or do something wrong.

I created a project with 3 class libraries (1 of them contains the tables from sql server). I made a ViewModel based on the tutorial from: "http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/how-to-use-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example", and now I want to be able to update the data in those tables, but I don't know how. I tried to do something but it failed.
`namespace BOL2.ViewModel
{
    public class NIRIO
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public Nullable Date { get; set; }

```
    public int NirID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("TypeID")]
    public int TipID { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EntryDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExitDate { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }


    public BOL2.tbl_NIR tbnir;
    public BOL2.tbl_I_O tblio { get; set; }`
```

This is my ViewModel. It contains data from those 2 tables (tbl_NIR, first 3, and the others from tbl_I_O. I saw something on my research that they had a repository class, but I don't now if I should do another class for the viewmodel or I sould use the 2 that I already have? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found the answer to this, so this topic is now resolved. In the edit controller of the other table add this: " tbl_I_O oi = db.tbl_I_O.Where(x => x.NirID == id).First(); " in the HttpGet. This answer is for those like me how use ADO.net Model database without viewmodel. Hope it helps and sorry for any bad spelling.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could do something similar to this.
public void UpdateCar(CarViewModel viewModel)
{
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
    {
        CarEntity dataModel = context.CarEntities.where(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id).First();

        dataModel.Name = viewModel.Name;
        dataModel.Type = viewModel.Type;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

You need to create your model objects from your view model and set the values for the models.
```

Comment: I saw the reference on this, and it did not work. I have the models in a different part of the project (BOL2 - class library). That library contains the models for each tables in my database. My question was if it is possible to make a Update action without repository, because I have separate repo for those 2 already? I'm new in programming, so please If you can explain it easy so I can understand. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It would be easy for me to explain you if you share more details on it.

Comment: Details Like Library that you used for models. How are you using your repository and what is the work flow designed to make use of repository. You could make update without repository too but it would be of no use from the project and framework perspective

Comment: I have the class library BOL2 that contains the models for each table. Then I have 2 other class librarys that contains repository data. like 
       
        public IEnumerable<tbl_NIR> GetALL()
        {
            return db.tbl_NIR.ToList();
        }
        public tbl_NIR GetByID(int Id)
        {
            return db.tbl_NIR.Find(Id);
        }
              public void Update(tbl_NIR nir)
        {
            db.Entry(nir).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
        }
        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

Comment: This is from DAL2 class library, and I have another in BLL2 that contains something like  public  private NirDb objDb;

        public NirBs()
        {
            objDb = new NirDb();
        }IEnumerable<BOL2.tbl_NIR> GetALL()
        {
            return objDb.GetALL();
        }
        public BOL2.tbl_NIR GetByID(int Id)
        {
            return objDb.GetByID(Id);
        } public void Update(BOL2.tbl_NIR nir)
        {
            objDb.Update(nir);
        }

Comment: So you could give the project reference of the class library BOL2 in the project where you want to do the update operation. By giving the project reference you would be able to access the model class and its properties in your current project where you want to perform the update operation. You could create the model class object with the values from your viewmodel class object and perform update operation as I suggested above.

Comment: Yes I made reference to the class library. Thank you!

Comment: Now I have a problem with Get action. When I try to create the view for the ViewModel it shows me the following: Unable to retrieve metadata for ViewModel. I'm looking into this now, I tried rebuilding, building, closeing it and open it agan but nothing. But the post action is good, I understand the concept for that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what is the method you used and didn't work. Just in case you tried to update the tables through the view, then you cannot do that. Because you have join
[inform IT explanation](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130855&seqNum=4) 
I recommend you to create a stored procedure in your database. Then call the procedure trough the code. It's secure and fast. [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767574/multiple-update-statements-in-one-storedprocedure)

Comment: This part of the code I used for the Update, but I was wandering if I have to do a repository for the viewmodel or I should just go with the 2 I already have, for table1 and table2?

Comment: //Get public actionresult Update(int? id){var nir = (from n in db.tbl_NIR join oi in db.tbl_I_O on n.ID equals oi.NirID where n.ID == id select new {ID = n.ID, Number = n.Number, other values, }).First(); var nirio = new BOL2.ViewModel.NIRIO(); {nirio.ID = nir.ID; nirio.Number = nir.Number; other values; return View(nirio);}

Comment: //Post public ActionResult Update(BOL2.ViewModel.NIRIO nirio){if(!ModelState.IsValid){return View(nirio);}tbl_NIR n=new tbl_NIR(){ID = nirio.tbnir.ID,Number=nirio.tbnir.Number,Date=nirio.tbnir.Date};            db.tbl_NIR.Attach(n); db.Entry(n).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified; db.SaveChanges(); //the same for tbl_I_O and return RedirectToAction("Index");}